# how to redirect if mobile and url = specific url

Tags: php, redirect, mobile

I have a php based website that I want to redirect the user to a mobile version of specific pages but only for those URL's, there are certain urls I want to keep as is for features to work as they currently do.

I know you can set a rule in config.php that says

```
if(!defined('_MOBILE') && !defined('_ADMIN') && $_SESSION['DV'] != 'true' && $_REQUEST['code'] == '' && $converting != 'true') {
        header("Location:".$config['MOBILE_URL'].$vinf);
        exit;
    }
```

But that will redirect on all pages if a mobile device is found, I just want to redirect for example if (mobile && location = "mysite/test"){//do redirect}

Any advice on how to go about this?  Would a rule need to be set on each individual php page that the redirect must happen on rather than in a config.php file?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

When I comment out the following then the browser does not redirect the user when on a mobile device:

```
/*
$config['GLOBAL_ENV'] = (strpos(php_sapi_name(), 'cgi')) ? 'env -i ' : NULL;
$config['MOBILE_URL'] = $config['base_url'].'/mobile';
if ($config['mobile_force_redirect'] == '1') {
    $config['IPHONE'] = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad")) $config['IPHONE'] = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
    $ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    if (stripos($ua,"android")) $config['IPHONE'] = stripos($ua,"android");
    if($config['IPHONE']) {
    if(!defined('_MOBILE') && !defined('_ADMIN') && $_SESSION['DV'] != 'true' && $_REQUEST['code'] == '' && $converting != 'true') {
        header("Location:".$config['MOBILE_URL'].$vinf);
        exit;
    }
    }
}*/
```

Comment: For starters, how are you detecting the mobile device? It looks like that's getting set *somehow* with '_MOBILE', but in the code example above, it looks like you're redirecting when _MOBILE is **not** defined.

Comment: I know that's not really your issue, though. Can you review the output of the $_SERVER array? You should be able to check for a match in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] (I think, off the top of my head)

Comment: haha just had to comment quick, my surname is Carlson as well, I'm not too great in PHP so bare with me.  See my edit in question.

Comment: Hej Carlson! (Okay I'm not actually Swedish) I think @ROOMAViX has your answer.

Comment: lol me neither I'm south african, looks like mobile detect will solve my problem thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) is a lightweight PHP class for detecting mobile devices (including tablets). It uses the User-Agent string combined with specific HTTP headers to detect the mobile environment.

Using that it's quite easy to only display content for a mobile:

```
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

// Check for any mobile device.
if ($detect->isMobile() && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "YOUR_URL_HERE"){
    header("Location:".$config['MOBILE_URL'].$vinf);
    exit;
}
else
   // other content
```

Comment: I like the looks of Mobile Detect—will have to check it out!

Comment: Great thanks, so basically I could use this code on the specific page I want to direct people to a mobile version, currently they are doing this check on the 'master' page if you want in the main config file, but if I take it there and place it directly on the index.php file for example then any other url that is hit wont redirect but the index.php one will right?  Will try this out but this seems to be my ticket to solving a problem I have had for a week now.  Thanks a ton!